# Retaining the value and state of dynamically generated HTML elements via jQuery after Postback in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a few HTML elements that get generated on the client side using jQuery.  However I loose all the dynamically generated elements and their associated values in Postback.  How can I recreate or maintain these elements upon Postback?

Comment: You can hold the values in hidden field. so after postback you can re-assign the values to controls. else use update panel if it is appropriate in your case.Just update the portion which is needed to be refreshed instead of entire postback.

Answer (score 0):

there is no straight forwrd way, instead you will have to rely on quirks.
You can apply priya's trick if your page is simple else checkout http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html